# Bluetooth permission already granted (permission handler)

Tags: android, flutter

I am working on bluetooth permission using permission_handler package.
My question is.. why bluetooth permission already granted? before I choose to deny or allow
My Snippet permission request:

```
 final status = await permissions.request();
  final bluetoothPermissions = [
    Permission.bluetooth,
    Permission.bluetoothConnect,
    Permission.bluetoothScan,
  ];
  for (var item in status.entries) {
    log(status.entries.toSet().toList().toString(), name: "ALL BL PERMISSIONS");
    if (bluetoothPermissions.contains(item.key)) {
      if (item.value.isGranted) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the Android Manifest:

```
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />
     <!-- required for API 18 - 30 -->
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
 <!-- API 31+ -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
            android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
```

Here is the log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLlNc.png)
Device I use: Huawei Honor 10 OS: HarmonyOS 3.0

Comment: Can you try to execute the App on a standard Android device on the emulator? While HarmonyOS is based on Android, it might be modified regarding how permissions are managed. To set up a virtual Android device emulator, see the instructions here: https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety/privacy-sandbox/download#emulator

Comment: I try using android emulator.. it also having the same behavior